# footnote inside mbox

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, framed

I know very similar questions have been asked, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

My original problem started using the `glossaries` package, using an acronym inside the `framed` environment, something like this:

```
\begin{framed}
bla bla \gls{Y2K} bla bla
\end{framed}
```

The expected behaviour was that next to Y2K should be a footnote, that footnote linking the acronyms, and the explaining text of the footnote at the bottom of the page.

Now I know the problem is not exactly with `glossaries` and `framed`, but with footnote and `\mbox` or `\fbox`.

Here's a minimal example that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Y2K}{name=Y2K,description={Bla bla bla}}

\begin{document}
% Bla bla  \gls{Y2K} bla bla % Works fine
\fbox{Bla bla  \gls{Y2K} bla bla} % doesn't work as expected

\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I use `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries`, `pdflatex` to compile.

So, the thing is that I need to use a footnote inside `\fbox`, because `framed` uses `\fbox` and `glossaries` uses footnote.

I already tried using this but didn't do anything:

```
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnote}
```

One last thing, this piece of code:

```
\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
```

I got it from here, maybe it could be tweaked to solve this problem.

**EDIT 06-DEC-2013**
After a long time I've found a problem with this solution. Instead of fbox I'm using the framed enviroment. When I use the first boxedgls inside framed there's no problem. If I use another framed enviroment after, it also generates the footnote (whether there is or not a gls inside).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Y2K}{name=Y2K,description={Bla bla bla}}

\newcommand\glsdoafterbox{}

\let\orgfbox\fbox
\def\fbox#1{\orgfbox{#1}\glsdoafterbox\def\glsdoafterbox{}}

\newcommand{\boxedgls}[1]{%
   \glstext{#1}%
   \ifglsused{#1}{}%
   {%
     \footnotemark
     \gappto\glsdoafterbox{\footnotetext{\glsentrydesc{#1}}\glsunset{#1}}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
Bla bla \boxedgls{Y2K} bla bla
\end{framed}

\newpage
\begin{framed}
Nothing here
\end{framed}

\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `\footnote` inside a box. For example, the following won't produce the footnote text:

```
\fbox{Some text\footnote{with a footnote}}.
```

Instead you need to use a combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` like this:

```
\fbox{Some text\footnotemark}\footnotetext{with a footnote}
```

Applying this to a glossary entry is complicated but can be done:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Y2K}{name=Y2K,description={Bla bla bla}}

\begin{document}

\fbox{Bla bla  \glstext{Y2K}\ifglsused{Y2K}{}{\footnotemark} bla 
bla}\ifglsused{Y2K}{}{\footnotetext{\glsentrydesc{Y2K}}\glsunset{Y2K}}

\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

For a more automated solution you could do:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Y2K}{name=Y2K,description={Bla bla bla}}

\newcommand\glsdoafterbox{}

\let\orgfbox\fbox
\def\fbox#1{\orgfbox{#1}\glsdoafterbox\def\glsdoafterbox{}}

\newcommand{\boxedgls}[1]{%
   \glstext{#1}%
   \ifglsused{#1}{}%
   {%
     \footnotemark
     \gappto\glsdoafterbox{\footnotetext{\glsentrydesc{#1}}\glsunset{#1}}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{Bla bla \boxedgls{Y2K} bla bla}

\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked! I've tried it with framed and it also worked

Comment: The "more automated solution" is exactly what I wanted (and works!), thank you very much

Comment: After a long time I've found a problem with this solution. Instead of `fbox` I'm using the `framed enviroment`. When I use the first `boxedgls` inside `framed` there's no problem. If I use another `framed` enviroment after, it also generates the footnote (whether there is or not a `gls` inside). I've edited my question with an example.