# Footnote inside description

Tags: glossaries, description

I had a very very similar problem with [footnote inside mbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104543/footnote-inside-mbox).

My original problem started using the `glossaries` package, using a glossary entry inside the `description` environment, a minimal example is shown here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bla}{name=bla,description={bla description}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\gls{bla}] pim pam pum % this doesn't work
% \item[pim pam pum] \gls{bla} % this works fine
\end{description}
\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The expected behaviour was that next to bla should be a footnote, that footnote linking the acronyms, and the explaining text of the footnote at the bottom of the page.

As you can see, the `\gls{bla}` inside the `item[]` is what is causing the problem.

I think the solution would be very similar to the one given in the question I mentioned, buy I don't have a clue how to do it.

Some aditional information:
I'm on Win 7 with miktex and texmaker.
Compilation:

- `pdflatex`
- `makeglossaries`
- `pdflatex`
- `pdflatex`

Comment: You could try loading the [`footnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote) package and add `\makesavenoteenv{description}` to your preamble.

Comment: @cgnieder Please make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the [`footnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote) package and add `\makesavenoteenv{description}` to your preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bla}{name=bla,description={bla description}}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{description}

% just for the example:
\setlength\textheight{3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\gls{bla}] pim pam pum % this doesn't work
% \item[pim pam pum] \gls{bla} % this works fine
\end{description}
\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,sanitize={name=false,description=false,symbol=true}]{glossaries}
    \glsdisablehyper

    \defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
    \makeglossaries

    \newglossaryentry{bla}{name=bla,description={bla description}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{description}
    \item[\gls{bla}] pim pam pum % this doesn't work
    % \item[pim pam pum] \gls{bla} % this works fine
    \end{description}
    \newpage
    \printglossaries
    \end{document}
```

[image]