# Footnote in framed environment

Tags: footnotes, framed

Some time ago I asked how I can use footnote environment and got good advise. But I had also the question what will happen if I need to use 2 or more footnote. I knew that I will meet such problem in short time. And this happens now. I tried small text

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}


\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep1pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\numberwithin{Hfootnote}{section}
\numberwithin{footnote}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newenvironment{ShadedDefinition}
{
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{definition}
}{%
\qed%
\end{definition}%
\end{Shaded}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test footnotes in framed environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{S1}
\begin{ShadedDefinition}
Let $A$ be algebra.
The norm\,\footnotemark
on module $A$ such that\,\footnotemark
\[\|ab\|\le\|a\|\,\|b\|\]
is called norm on algebra $A$.
\end{ShadedDefinition}
\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{
If algebra $A$ is division algebra,
then norm is called
absolute value
and we use notation $|a|$ for norm of $A$-number $a$.
}
\stepcounter{Hfootnote}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{
The inequality
\[\|ab\|\le\|a\|\,\|b\|\]
follows from the theorem
...
}
\end{document}
```

and output works like I expected. But I saw one unexpected error. Log file reports me

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

and I see that reference 1.1 is disabled. I saw also other error as well:

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{Hfootnote.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored.

Comment: See also [glossaries - footnote inside mbox - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104543/footnote-inside-mbox). And the problem is probably solved in [beamer - How to make multiple \footnotemark and \footnotetext match? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370600/how-to-make-multiple-footnotemark-and-footnotetext-match).